# How To Remove Some Characters from a String in Python or just Extract some lines from it?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am using Pandas for receiving live gold prices, I just want to clean the output so it can look good and readable. **Please help me with this**.

My code:

```
import pandas as pd
d = pd.read_html('http://www.livepriceofgold.com/pakistan-gold-price.html')
type(d)
a=len(d)
i=1
df = d[3]
finalString=df.to_string()
print(finalString)
```

and The output is:

```
     0                                 1             2
0 NaN  Gold Rate in PKR Pakistani rupee          Rate
1 NaN         Gold Rate per Gram in PKR      7 889.65
2 NaN           Gold Rate per Oz in PKR    245 368.02
3 NaN           Gold Rate per KG in PKR  7 889 646.96
4 NaN         Gold Rate per Tola in PKR     92 023.26
```

I want this type of output:

```
Gram in PKR:      7 889.65
Oz in PKR  :      245 368.02
KG in PKR  :      7 889 646.96
Tola in PKR:     92 023.26
```

Or just Extract the Rates in variables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `header=0` parameter for first row of data to columns names, `thousands=' '` for remove spaces in [`read_html`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_html.html) in first step.

Then remove first column by indexing with [`DataFrame.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html), set new columns names and change values in `Text` column by [`Series.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.replace.html):

```
url = 'http://www.livepriceofgold.com/pakistan-gold-price.html'
df = pd.read_html(url, header=0, thousands=' ')[3].iloc[:, 1:]
df.columns= ['Text','Rates']

df['Text'] = df['Text'].replace('Gold Rate per ', '', regex=True)
print (df)
          Text       Rates
0  Gram in PKR     7889.65
1    Oz in PKR   245368.02
2    KG in PKR  7889646.96
3  Tola in PKR    92023.26
```

Answer (score -1):

**so far, I have used this to remove every thing and then split these strings and extract the values i need using split function**

```
 fs=fs.replace("Gold Rate per Gram in PKR","")
    fs=fs.replace("Gold Rate per Oz in PKR","")
    fs=fs.replace("Gold Rate per KG in PKR","")
    fs=fs.replace("Gold Rate per Tola in PKR","")
    fs=fs.replace("Gold Rate in PKR Pakistani rupee","")
    fs=fs.replace("Rate","")
    fs=fs.replace("0 NaN","")
    fs=fs.replace("1 NaN","")
    fs=fs.replace("2 NaN","")
    fs=fs.replace("3 NaN","")
    fs=fs.replace("4 NaN","")
    #print(fs.split())
    single= fs.split()
```